# Can i use Linq with SQLite if the tables (and table schemas) are generated at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, system.data.sqlite

Let's say I create a random table "MyTable" using a SQL statement ("CREATE TABLE MyTable (col1, col2)").  How can I then use Linq to query that table?

from t in MyTable
select t.col1

or perhaps

from t in db["MyTable"]
select t("col1")

Perhaps this is not possible.

Comment: define Linq... the ADO provider for SQLite that Diego is referring to supports Linq for Entities, i'm pretty sure that Linq for Sql only works with MS SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you're looking for is a SQLite data provider for Linq. Basically is a library called System.Data.SQLite that enables you to query SQLite databases using Linq.

**EDIT:**

Ok, since what you want is LinqToSQL support for SQLite, I will suggest you check this article at CodeProject.com: [LinqToSQL: Comprehensive Support for SQLite](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/linq/linqToSql_7.aspx). It features a full tutorial on the topic.

Comment: are you sure it supports Linq for Sql too? im only aware that it supports Linq for Entities